# Rest Button on Click Close in MOdal

Tags: r, shiny

i am creating an user registration application which accepts the user inputs like:username,Fullname,Email,contact number.

After clicking create button i am able to display modal message stating user registered . Onclick of close button i want my tabpanel created to reset all the textinput to its original data.

```
1)Created one tabpanel with title.
2)Created all the input and its types.
3)Created Modal successfully.
4)Even tried with shinyjs::reset() funtion as well.
```

Code for Ui.R:

```
tabPanel(title="User Management",id ="user",shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
       fluidRow(
               column(5,textInput("uname","User Name")),
               column(5,textInput("fname","Full Name"))),
       fluidRow(
                column(5,textInput("email","Email Id")),
                column(5,numericInput("contactnum","Contactnumber",value=NULL))),
        fluidRow(
                column(5,selectInput("country", label = "Country:",
                                      choices = list("India","USA"), 
                                      selected = 1)),
                column(5,selectInput("state", label = "State:",
                                      choices =list("Karnataka","Kerala"), 
                                      selected = 1))),
        fluidRow(column(5,numericInput("zip","ZIP Code",value=NULL)),
        fluidRow(
                  column(5,passwordInput("pwd1","Password")),
                  column(5,passwordInput("pwd2","Confirm Password"))),
        fluidRow(
                  column(12,actionButton("userCreate", "Create User"), 
                  style="color: #fff; 
                  background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"))),
                       br(),
              )
     )
```

Server.R:

```
observeEvent(input$userCreate,{
if(postuser() == 200)
{
  showModal(modalDialog(
    title = "Success",
    "User is successfully added!"
   footer = tagList(
        actionButton("Close", "Close")
      )
    )))
}
})

observeEvent(input$Close,{
 reset("user")
}
)
```

Update and Tries:

```
Even tried with shinyjs::reset("user") funtion and shinyjs::js$reset("user")function as well.
```

Please help me out with this . And i need logical code for list of all the counties and states.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
observeEvent(input$Close,{
     #reset("user")
     shinyjs::reset("uname")
     shinyjs::reset("fname")  
     #the remaining fields id's you would like to reset
}
```

The problem was giving the wrong div id's to `reset`, hence nothing happened after click `close`. To understand what I'm talking about have a look at

```
print(tabPanel(title="User Management",id ="user",shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                  fluidRow(
                      column(5,textInput("uname","User Name")),
                      column(5,textInput("fname","Full Name")))))
```

Comment: It is my pleasure. Please accept and upvote my answer when you can. Thanks

Comment: Can you help me out with drop down list for country and states???
Which works in basic web applications to choose a country based on country choose states and cities

Comment: I have a list of countries which you can find [here](https://github.com/AbubakerSuliman/Shiny-login-page). Unfortunately, I do not have a link or source you can use. But I think it can be done by preparing countries, states and cities dataframe or "database" then use `updateSelectInput` when country or city selected by user.

Comment: Thanks you . I will give a try on this and let you know does that work